# Stack Overflow Unveils the Next Steps in Computer Security

Tags: discussion

See that an April Fools joke has gone up early, but even if written as is it still would be posted the day before, don't think that's how they normally work! When they are late the fool is on the fooler, not sure what happens when they are early!

https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/30/stack-overflow-unveils-next-steps-computer-security

Comment: They usually roll out early. As soon as it's April 1st somewhere on the world, the feature will be implemented.

Comment: That explains it then - look forward to tomorrow or April 1st depending on timezone :)

Comment: While we're at it... [Security.SE is interested](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/155375/5405).